# Acorecms Auto Login New User After Registration plugin installation error: Installation failed: Could not create directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose, content-management-system, azerothcore

When trying to add the Auto Login New User After Registration plugin in acorecms I get 'Installation failed: Could not create directory.'

Fresh docker install of acorecms, couldn't install any plugins. Always states the same error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I got into the running cms docker container and ran 'chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www' and it seemed to work. For anyone that may run into a similar issue